# Not able to disable full screen in window 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop, start-menu, fullscreen

I have tried the steps in the following link :

[how to disable full screen on windows 10](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-10/how-do-i-get-rid-full-screen-start-screen-windows-10)

But eve after following the steps, it is showing as a full screen and not showing the desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when the Tablet mode is on. [Disable the tablet mode first](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3755-tablet-mode-turn-off-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: ok, nice to hear it. Mark my reply as answer to "close" the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Windows 10: How to enable or disable full screen start menu.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLlgnd6VtkA)

[Windows 10: How to enable or disable tablet mode.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-6xinKKLo8)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.